# SpeechSynthesizer .NET control pitch

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I'm trying to change the pitch of spoken text via SSML and the  .NET SpeechSynthesizer (System.Speech.Synthesis)

```
SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
builder.AppendSsml(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\ssml1.xml");
synthesizer.Speak(builder);
```

The content of the ssml1.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ssml:speak version="1.0"
xmlns:ssml="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
xml:lang="en-US">
<ssml:sentence>
Your order for <ssml:prosody pitch="+30%" rate="-90%" >8 books</ssml:prosody>
will be shipped tomorrow.
</ssml:sentence>
</ssml:speak>
```

The rate is recognized: "8 books"  is speaken much slower than the rest, but no matter what value is set for "pitch", it makes no difference ! Allowed values can be found here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.2.4

Am I missing something or is changing the pitch just not supported by the Microsoft Speech engine ?

fritz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the engine `SsmlParser` used by `System.Speech` accepts a `pitch` attribute in the `ProcessProsody` method, it does not process it.

It only processes the `range`, `rate`, `volume` and `duration` attributes. It also parses `contour` but is processed as `range` (not sure why)...

**Edit**: if you don't really need to read the text from a SSML xml file, you can create the text programatically.
Instead of

```
builder.AppendSsml(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\ssml1.xml");
```

use

```
builder.Culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
builder.StartVoice(builder.Culture);
builder.StartSentence();

builder.AppendText("Your order for ");

builder.StartStyle(new PromptStyle() { Emphasis = PromptEmphasis.Strong, Rate = PromptRate.ExtraSlow });
builder.AppendText("8 books");
builder.EndStyle();

builder.AppendText(" will be shipped tomorrow.");

builder.EndSentence();
builder.EndVoice();
```

Comment: I wonder if there is any other speech engine api that can be used with .net and which processes pitch commands ?

Comment: @fritz: there are not many .NET APIs. There are many native APIs, not many of them are "free", though. I have used **eSpeak** (not .NET) with success - better output than from `System.Speech` but it did not read SSML well.

Comment: Is there a way to sing with .NET speech or any alternative? I'm looking for an API that supports the three features of control: 1) Speech 2) Accurate stable pitch 3) Duration control. Is there such a thing? I obviously prefer a musically-driven API.